# "java.lang.NullPointerException" when trying to install Android SDK

Tags: java, android, macos, sdk, nullpointerexception

(first, I apologize for my english, it's not my actual speak language)

I'm trying since yesterday to install the Android SDK.

I'm on a Mac, OSX **10.8.3**, with java **1.6.0_51**, and the Android SDK version is **adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522**.

When I launch the SDK manager (through Eclipse **or** via the CLI), I can see the window, I can select the SDK versions I wish to install, but when I click on the *install packages...* button, it crashes.

The stack trace of the crash is :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.getFontList(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.FontRegistry.filterData(FontRegistry.java:465)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.FontRegistry.createFont(FontRegistry.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.FontRegistry.defaultFontRecord(FontRegistry.java:563)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.FontRegistry.defaultFontData(FontRegistry.java:575)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.FontRegistry.getFontData(FontRegistry.java:591)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.dialogFontIsDefault(Dialog.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.applyDialogFont(Dialog.java:998)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.createContents(Dialog.java:756)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.SdkUpdaterChooserDialog.create(SdkUpdaterChooserDialog.java:316)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.SwtUpdaterData.updateOrInstallAll_WithGUI(SwtUpdaterData.java:232)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.PackagesPage.onButtonInstall(PackagesPage.java:1033)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.PackagesPage.access$1100(PackagesPage.java:83)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.PackagesPage$10.widgetSelected(PackagesPage.java:367)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.open(SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.java:148)
at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.SdkUpdaterWindow.open(SdkUpdaterWindow.java:111)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:356)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:334)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:120)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

When I was searching for more information on the internet, some persons seems to have the same problem, and says it's because of Fonts Cache problems... but I check the fonts duplicates : no problems, and cleaning the font cache as it was described, and the error still occuring.

I really need to get this fixed, I hope anyone here can help me.

Thanks in advance,

**EDIT**: This question is marked as duplicate but the solutions listed there did not solve the issue. The solution was to disable all fonts in Font Book. One of the installed fonts is corrupted and this is causing SWT to break.

Comment: This question seems to be the same as your's:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557561/nullpointerexception-when-installing-the-android-sdk-on-mac-os-x

Comment: As I said, the solution proposed in the other topic isn't working for me... :/

Comment: Ok, to avoid these comments, you should list the sources that did not help. Have you checked whether you have the latest Java?

Comment: This issue may be related to this bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=295025 so an update may help

Comment: Yep, I have the latest java version on mac, my fonts cache is cleared, and I still have the problem... 
I will try to update Eclipse, keep you in touch.

Comment: I finally fix it !
I have disactivated all my fonts, then try, and all was finally good.
It appears that one of my fonts is corrupted... now, I need to find which it is.
Thank you for your help !

Comment: @Leny You should post this as an answer. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to install a basic Eclipse and add the sdk and plugin separately. You can follow the official guidelines listed here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

I have no clue whether this helps or not but I have no better guess but since nothing seems to work for you, it's worth trying.

Comment: The problem is fixed, but I definitely try this way for my next installation.
Thanks :)

Comment: Great, please submit an answer for your own question and accept it when possible. It is better to have a question with the correct answer . Also, you'll possibly get reps for it.